# SignalR For Multiplayer Game Development

Tags: javascript, multiplayer, .net, jquery

I've been working with `SignalR` for live chat and notifications in .NET platform and was wondering how much is it worth for working on games development? I've made some jQuery browser games and I want to make them multiplayer. Is there any performance issues if I use SignalR for games development? Need some detailed info about it. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like it'll depend totally on your game. Are you making a turn-based game? (Probably won't matter much then.) Are you making a twitch shooter? (Run some tests.)

Comment: check out http://shootr.signalr.net